# How to print a list of numbers and their average?

Tags: python

For my assignment, I have to create a program that lets the user enter several numbers. I also want to create a list with all the numbers and their average.

But how do I create a code for the list of numbers?

I should exit with a number such as 0 or -999.

One line has invalid syntax.

```
print (number_list[i], end = " ")
```

Here is my code.

```
number_list = []
sum = 0.0

user_number = eval(input("Please enter a number (-999 quits): "))

# Loop until the user is ready to quit
while (user_number != -999):
    number_list.append(user_number)
    sum = sum + user_number
    user_number = eval(input("Please enter a number (-999 quits): "))

# Make sure the user entered something
if (len(number_list) != 0):
    # Compute average
    average = sum / len(number_list)

    # Do output
    print ("Using the numbers:")

    for i in range(len(number_list)):
        # Note the end = " " at the end will keep the output on
        #   the same line
        print (number_list[i], end = " ")

    # Note the \n at the start of this line is needed because
    #   the previous print statement ended with a comma.  This
    #   \n will move the cursor to the next line
    print ("\nThe average is:", average)
else:
    print ("No values were entered")
```

Comment: Well asked question!

Comment: Please get your indentation right, your code will not work!

Comment: SyntaxErrors are detected by Python have have nothing to do with the IDE.  But I will note that IDLE would have automatically added the indents that are missing. Printing the average should be after the loop, which is after the `else` part of the `for` statement.

Comment: @StefGeysels I don't agree.

Comment: I need help with the line print(number, end=" "). The syntax is still broken.

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code letter for letter but no syntax errors arise. Try pasting the actual code, or if it is your actual code, check if you're mixing tabs and spaces, which you should never do and replace all tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: Everything was written with four spaces. EDIT: I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Python's indentation rules, any compound statement needs to have at least one statement indented after it.

Let's focus on this section of your code:

```py
for i in range(len(number_list)):
print (number_list[i], end = " ")
print ("\nThe average is:", average)
else:
print ("No values were entered")
```

A `for` loop is a compound statement as it needs stuff indented after it. You need to indent them accordingly. Something like:

```py
for i in range(len(eggs)):
    print(eggs[i])
```

The pythonic way to loop over stuff is just to use the value instead of getting the index and then finding it. Python's `for` loop is more like a `foreach` loop than an actual `for` loop. A remake would look like:

```py
for spam in eggs:
    print(spam)
```

Also, you have a check for if there aren't any numbers. Use a normal `if` statement for that, not one in the loop. The `else` behind a loop will run when the main part (`while` or `for`) finishes without a `break`.

This:

```py
for spam in eggs:
    print(spam)
else:
    print("Nothing")
```

Is not the same as this:

```py
if eggs:
    for spam in eggs:
        print(spam)
else:
    print("Nothing")
```

Here's the fixed section :D

```py
# If statement to check if list is truthy (nonempty)
if number_list:
    # Note the for loop's target 'number'
    for number in number_list:
        # Note indentation.
        print(number, end=" ")
    print("\nThe average is:", average)

else:
    print("No values were entered")
```

EDIT: You also have indentation errors after the `while` loop above this section. I'll leave that to you to fix :)

Comment: The syntax is still wrong with the line "print(number, end=" ")"

Comment: Which error did it give you? IndentationError or just SyntaxError.

Comment: I'm using the IDLE editor, and it says "Invalid syntax".